# How I get a TypeObject Error in dart test

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, exception

Im trying to create a test for get a error in type convertion

```
  modelTest = VersionModel(
        forceUpdate: true,//bool
        buildNumber: 1222,//int
        versionNumber: "2",//String
      );
```

My json that has a wrong type in the object

```
 final jsonError = {
      "force_update": "false",
      "build_number": 31003.,
      "version_number": "3.1.0"
    };
```

My test

```
 test("Should be return instance of VersionModel from json", () {
      final json = modelTest!.toJson();
      expect(VersionModel.fromJson(json),
         Exception());
    });
```

message: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool?' in type cast

What I tryed

```
 test("Should be return an error of a instance VersionModel to json",
        () {
      try {
        VersionModel.fromJson(jsonError);
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e, isInstanceOf<TypeError>());
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the error like this. The error in the serialisation will be caught and throws exception as follows. Then it will check the type which was  thrown at serialisation and match with the excepted value.

```
    test("Should be return instance of VersionModel from json", () {
    expect(() {
      try {
        VersionModel.fromJson(jsonEncode(jsonError));
      } catch (e) {
        throw Exception();
      }
    }, throwsA(isA<Exception>()));
  });
```

According to this It will throws an exception for the all error types that comes from the json.